# problem with copying directory files to another directory

Tags: bash

So I want to copy some files from one directory to another.
Essentially, I want to capture the directory path to a variable, say, "pathname" and use 
 
"cp-r $pathname ." to copy file1 and file2 to to a new folder in which I made using mkdir and have cd'ed into (hence the "." as the second command line argument).

source_to_copy_from:

```
home/folder1/folder2/file1
home/folder1/folder2/file2
```

destination_to_copy_to:

```
home/newfolder1/newfolder2/file1
home/newfolder1/newfolder2/file2
```

I did:

```
pathname=$"$(pwd)"
//code to make the newfolder1 here
cp -r $"$pathname" .
```

But there appears to be nothing in the new pathname that was supposed to be copied in. 
Also am using Mac bash 
also quite beginner to bash

Comment: Try something like this: https://www.ideone.com/PrBCgJ

Comment: You have more `$` than needed.

Comment: @Jetchisel removing the $ didn't affect anything: pathname="$(pwd)";
#//code to make the newfolder1 here;
cp -r "$pathname" . still results in nothing new.

Comment: @zedfoxus not sure, but changing to ./ didn't change anything.

Comment: @user230493215 put an echo statement under your pathname declaration. Run the program. Tell me what it echoes out: https://www.ideone.com/ONIOho

Comment: @zedfoxus /Users/account/desktop/files/home/newfolder1/newfolder2

Comment: Great. Are file1 and file2 that you want to copy in that particular directory?

Comment: Yes, I want to copy file1 and file 2 from folder1/folder2 to newfolder1/newfolder2, @zedfoxus

Comment: So, where is folder1/folder2? Is it under /Users/account/desktop/files/home/folder1/folder2?

Comment: @zedfoxus it is under /Users/account/desktop/files/src/folder1/folder2.

Comment: `cp -v home/folder1/folder2/file{1,2} home/newfolder1/newfolder2/` That works with your particular filename, `file1` and `file2` since `file{1,2}` expands to that and it is called brace expansion. Change `file{1,2}` to a glob `*` to match all files but you should use nullglob `shopt -s nullglob`

Comment: @zedfoxus Yes, it is under /Users/account/desktop/files/home/folder1/folder2,

Comment: Good to know. If I understand correctly, your bash script is going to be in /Users/account/desktop/files/home/newfolder1/newfolder2. You will cd into  /Users/account/desktop/files/home/newfolder1/newfolder2 and run the bash script. You want the bash script to copy /Users/account/desktop/files/home/folder1/folder2/file1 and /Users/account/desktop/files/home/folder1/folder2/file2 to /Users/account/desktop/files/home/newfolder1/newfolder2. Correct?

Comment: @Jetchisel I believe that the pathname "home/folder1/folder2" is set to a variable "pathname". How would I access file1 and file2. Is it just "$pathname"/*

Comment: I think Jetchiesel is on the right track. I'll have you both figure this out. He'll help you faster than I can.

Comment: @zedfoxus bash script (sh file) itself is located in /Users/account/desktop/files. I will cd into /Users/account/desktop/files/home/newfolder1/newfolder2, and run the bash file, correct. Exactly correct for the rest.

Comment: @Jetchisel I think -v is for files, and -r is for folders, right?

Comment: `-v` means verbose.

Comment: @Jetchisel -v is verbose, how does it work?(tried to find documentation, but not sure)

Comment: `info cp` or `cp --help`, and of course `man cp`